# How to test two lines from the same model are parallel

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

If I have two sets of data each with 5 entries for X&Y, I built a model to incorporate this using a dummy/indicator variable for when X is in Set B, so obviously I get two parallel lines;
$$y=\alpha + \beta_{1}x +\beta_{2}\mathbb{1}_{x \in B}+\epsilon$$
 where epsilon is N(0,1). 
How I do formally test the hypothesis that the two lines are parallel??

Comment: .........ST221?......................................

Comment: Why is $\epsilon$ *standard normal*? It would be unusual to now the variance, let alone for it to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to test for parallelism of the two lines is to add an interaction term:

$$y=\alpha + \beta_{1}x +\beta_{2}\mathbb{1}_{x \in B}+\beta_{3}\,x \cdot\mathbb{1}_{x \in B}+\varepsilon$$

and then test whether $\beta_3$ differs from zero. If you reject the null, the conclusion is that the lines are not parallel. (You can't actually prove they *are* parallel.)

This can be done either as a t-test in the usual regression output or as an F test.

Comment: But I am asked do this as a hypothesis in R, I was thinking F test or T test as the smaller model is nested in the larger?

Comment: See my edit. Is this for some class? If so, you should really have mentioned that.

Comment: OK thank you! Ive done the T test, but how would you go about doing the F test...apologies I am a beginner at R :)

Comment: One way would be to fit one model via `lm`, then the other\* and supplying both `lm` objects to `anova` (smaller model frst). $\:$ \* `update` could be used when fitting the second model but isn't necessary. $\qquad$ See `?lm`, `?anova` (and `?update`, if you use that)